# Ansible: virt module XML error

Tags: xml, ansible, libvirt

I'm trying to define a VM using the virt module and a XML file. This task:

```
 - name: Define VM using the XML file
   virt: command=define
         name={{ new_vm_name }}
         xml={{ vm_images_path }}/{{ new_vm_xml }}
   remote_user: root
   delegate_to: "{{ hyperv }}"
```

fails with this error:

```
failed: [vm-002 -> nat] => {"failed": true}
msg: (domain_definition):1: Start tag expected, '<' not found
/var/lib/libvirt/images//vm-002-ver1.1.0-00042.xml
```

while this works:

```
 - name: Define VM using the XML file
   command: virsh define {{ vm_images_path }}/{{ new_vm_xml }}
   remote_user: root
   delegate_to: "{{ hyperv }}"
```

XML file is the same in both cases, any idea of why the first one fails? I do always prefer using modules than custom commands so I'd really like to make the first one work.

Comment: have you tried quoting parameters of `xml=` and/or `name=`?

Comment: Sorry for the late response @Mxx, but did not work. I've got the same error! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The `xml` parameter of the `virt` module takes a XML string, not a filename.

You could achieve what you want like this:

```
- name: Define VM using the XML file
   virt: command=define
         name={{ new_vm_name }}
         xml={{ lookup('template', './libvirt_create_template.j2') }}
   remote_user: root
   delegate_to: "{{ hyperv }}"
```

The file you reference in the lookup is located on the Ansible control server (i.e. where you run your playbooks).

By using a template lookup, you can have the VM specific settings replaces with the values from the inventory for the VM you are installing.